# Chart.MVC pass function OnAnimationComplete

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, chart.js

I implemented a chart.MVC in MVC5 , I have this problem when using the OnAnimationComplete

It seems that the problem is a function pass through JSON.parse.

Enclosed is my code.

```
var complexChartBar = new BarChart();
complexChartBar.ChartConfiguration.Responsive = true;
complexChartBar.ChartConfiguration.OnAnimationComplete = "function () {" +
    "console.log(ctx)" +
    "var ctx = this.chart.ctx;" +
    "ctx.font = this.scale.font;" +
    "ctx.fillStyle = this.scale.textColor" +
    "ctx.textAlign = center;" +
    "ctx.textBaseline = bottom;" +
    "this.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {" +
        "dataset.bars.forEach(function(bar) {" +
            "ctx.fillText(bar.value, bar.x, bar.y - 5);" +
            "});" +
        "})" +
    "}";
```

and console you can see this

```
var options = JSON.parse('{"responsive":true,"onAnimationComplete":"function () {console.log(ctx)var ctx = this.chart.ctx;ctx.font = this.scale.font;ctx.fillStyle = this.scale.textColorctx.textAlign = center;ctx.textBaseline = bottom;this.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {dataset.bars.forEach(function(bar) {ctx.fillText(bar.value, bar.x, bar.y - 5);});})}"}');
```

and I get the following error

```
Chart.js:700 Uncaught TypeError: onComplete.apply is not a function
```

Thanks.

Comment: That is the result of `console.log(ctx);`?

Comment: No, is an error in the browser console.

Comment: Just for testing purposes, try changing `OnAnimationComplete = "function(){ alert('test');}";`

Comment: Yes, I have already done this previously and I feel the same.
From what I 've seen the problem is in the JSON.parse().
It does not work well when you pass a function.

Comment: Actually `JSON.parse` works: https://jsfiddle.net/765mbeq3/

Comment: I keep going the same error in my project.
From what I 've seen in your example , you run a true alert and gives you back the responsive .
But if you change the alert so that you return the onAnimationComplete , brings you back a string.
The function is not executed.